# Custom plotting

Tags: highcharts

I have to create controls based on an object that I'm getting from a db call. The object can be anything, so the chart has to be created dynamically. To illustrate my issue lets say that the object looks like

```
var obj = [{name:"int",data:[2,5,8,11,12]},
           {name:"double",data:[1.1,4.1,7.1,10.1,11]}]
```

After parsing the obj the user can select what they want to plot. Whether they want to see `int` or `double` on the x/y Axis. Then plot the series they want to see. My issue is that every time I plot the series no matter how I format it plots the series with the yAxis and the value's array index on the xAxis. How could I make it so the user can plot the int/double relation using either series? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by int/double relation? Could you explain and maybe create simple mockups?

Comment: well what I ended up doing was to combine the series like: `data:[[2,1.1],[5,4.1],[8,7.1]...]` which I think that is what the client wants since the data to be charted has no consistency.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use select html obejct, then catch select event and i.e addSeries() function to chart. 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()